# Drupal 7 and module_invoke_all

Tags: php, drupal

Take a look at the `delete` method in the [Artwork controller class](https://github.com/LearningDrupal7Development/artwork/blob/master/artwork.controller.inc) over at GitHub (code samples from Drupal book `Drupal 7 Module Development`.

In particular, take note of line 166:

```
module_invoke_all('entity_delete', $artwork, 'artwork');
```

In this case, $artwork is an out-of-scope variable. Am I correct in assuming that this should have been the following instead:

```
module_invoke_all('entity_delete', $artworks, 'artwork');
```

If that is the case, would this invoke once for each entity in the $artworks array or just once overall?

Answer (score 1):

Nice find.  To me though, it seems like line 166 belongs in the foreach loop on 152.

```
foreach ($artworks as $artwork_id => $artwork) {
```

hook_entity_delete handles a single entity and other parts of that ActivityController class handle a single artwork, not an array of artwork objects.

I'll feel more comfy going with a disclaimer that this is just what I'm concluding after a little bit of looking.  Don't have enough time to be 100%.  Just putting it out there.